# C++ error distinguishing specialization when passing a const array

Tags: c++, template-specialization

consider the code

```
     template <class A>
     class B;

     template <class A>
     class B<const A>{};

     template <class A, int N>
     class B<A[N]>{};

     template <class A>
     class B<A*>{};

     template <class A>
     class B<A&>{};
```

The following template instantiations work fine:

```
     A<int*&>
     A<const int*>
     A<int*[3]>
```

but the following one doesn't work:

```
     A<const int[3]>
```

Is there some reason that this particular combination is invalid or is it perhaps a bug with g++4.6.3?

By the way I managed to get around this using SFINAE and boost::disable_if<>, so at least the problem is solved.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that the error in question is an ambiguous class template instantiation and it couldn't decide between the overload for const or the overload for an array.

**EDIT2**

This has nothing to do with pointers, here's the full context:

I'm going through the book *C++ Template Metaprogramming* and am doing question 2-3 (Chapter 2 question 3) which says:

Use the type traits facilities to implement a type_descriptor class template, whose instances, when streamed, print the type of their template parameters:
NOTE: we cannot use RTTI to the same effect since, according to 18.5.1 [lib.type.info] paragraph 7 of the standard, typeid(T).name() is not guaranteed to return a meaningful result.

My solution (including the the workaround for the compilation error) is as follows:

```
    //QUESTION 2-3
    template <class T, class enable = void>
    struct type_descriptor
    {
      std::string operator()() const
      {
        return "Unknown";
      }
    };

    //specializations for primitive types
    #define TYPE_DESC_SPEC(type) template <>    \
      struct type_descriptor<type,void>     \
      {std::string operator()() const{return #type;}};

    TYPE_DESC_SPEC(int)
    TYPE_DESC_SPEC(long)
    TYPE_DESC_SPEC(void)
    TYPE_DESC_SPEC(short)
    TYPE_DESC_SPEC(unsigned char)
    TYPE_DESC_SPEC(unsigned short)
    TYPE_DESC_SPEC(unsigned long)

    //specializations for modifiers *, const, &, and [N]

    template <class T>
    struct type_descriptor<T&,void>
    {std::string operator()(){return type_descriptor<T>()() + " &";}};

    template <class T>
    struct type_descriptor<T*,void>
    {std::string operator()(){return type_descriptor<T>()() + " *";}};

    //Replace void with what's in the comment for the workaround.
    template <class T>
    struct type_descriptor<const T, void/*typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_array<T> >::type*/>
    {std::string operator()(){return type_descriptor<T>()() + " const";}};

    template <class T>
    struct type_descriptor<T(*)(),void>
    {std::string operator()(){return type_descriptor<T>()() + " (*)()";}};

    template <class T, class U>
    struct type_descriptor<T(*)(U),void>
    {std::string operator()(){return type_descriptor<T>()() + " (*)(" + type_descriptor<U>()() + ")";}};

    template <class T, int N>
    struct type_descriptor<T[N],void>
    {
      std::string operator()()
      {
        std::stringstream s;
        s << type_descriptor<T>()() << " [" << N << "]";
        return s.str();
      }
    };

    template <class T>
    struct type_descriptor<T[],void>
    {std::string operator()(){return type_descriptor<T>()() + " []";}};

    //Now overload operator<< to allow streaming of this class directly

    template <class T>
    std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & s, type_descriptor<T> t)
    {
      return s << t();
    }
    //END QUESTION 2-3
```

Sample usage is:

```
      std::cout << "\nQuestion 2-3 results\n";
      std::cout << type_descriptor<int*>() << std::endl;
      std::cout << type_descriptor<int*[3]>() << std::endl;
      std::cout << type_descriptor<std::string*>() << std::endl;
      std::cout << type_descriptor<const int&>() << std::endl;
      std::cout << type_descriptor<const int *const&>() << std::endl;
      std::cout << type_descriptor<int[4]>() << std::endl;
      std::cout << type_descriptor<int(*)()>() << std::endl;
      std::cout << type_descriptor<int*&(*)(const char &)>() << std::endl;
      std::cout << type_descriptor<int*&>() << std::endl;
      std::cout << type_descriptor<int[]>() << std::endl;
      std::cout << type_descriptor<const long[]>() << std::endl;
```

and the corresponding output is (when the workaround is in, otherwise it doesn't compile on that last one):

```
int *

int * [3]

Unknown *

int const &

int const * const &

int [4]

int (*)()

int * & (*)(Unknown const &)

int * &

int []

long const []
```

So C++ is able to differentiate pointers and arrays for the template parameters, is able to correctly, recursively, separate compound types and output the correct result, except for `const A[]`.  It needs help with that one

Comment: Going to guess at this - but I think `const int[3]` decays into `const int*`

Comment: @AdrianCornish no that's not it, see the edit.  Besides if that were it the third valid example I put shouldn't work either.

Comment: 3rd would work because `const int *` is different than `int *` - trying (unsuccessfully) to find the section of the standard that documents the decay ;-)

Comment: c++2011 8.3.5.5 .... "After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or “function returning T” is
adjusted to be “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T,” respectively.

Comment: Opps example 3 will decay to `int **` - my mistake

Comment: Well, it's ambiguous... which behaviour did you expect?

Comment: @KerrekSB well that depends on what exactly a `const int[]` consists of, is it an array of `const int`s or a `const` array of `int`s?  I expected it to be one of those two, I didn't expect it to be ambiguous at all

Comment: @AdrianCornish see my second edit, I don't think the decaying of an array to a pointer has anything to do with this one, because passing an array vs. a pointer creates different outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array type with a const element type is both a const qualified type (the const  applies bidirectionally) and an array type.

So you should fix the specializations.

Comment: Why is it that way for arrays and not for pointers or references?

Comment: because it doesnt make sense for pointers. pointers can be const and can point to const. and references being an indirection too could conceptually also have two different consts but since a reference cannot be changed to refer to different things the const on the reference itself is forbidden. on the other side, the value of an arrayis nothing more than all its elements, without indirection. so it makes sense that const applies bidirectionally.

Comment: Is there any advantage to this definition over considering `const int[]` to be an array of const ints?  I mean in the sense that the template specializations above would not be ambiguous and the array specialization is what would be instantiated.

Comment: if it would not be like this, you could not overload for T const and T and have const T[] take the former and T[] take the latter.